# Server Broker, SqlDependency ошибка включения

Tags: c#, sql-server

Захожу в SQL Manager Studio в упор вижу что включено отслеживание изменений, захожу в свойство таблицы, которая меня интересует, там тоже включено отслеживание изменений, но при билде ПО мне пишет следующую ошибку :

`SQL Server Service Broker для текущей базы данных не включен, поэтому оповещения не поддерживаются. Включите Service Broker для этой базы данных, чтобы использовать оповещения.`

Comment: Ну так, видимо, у вас Change Tracking включён, а Service Broker - нет (это независимые вещи). Service Broker включается в опциях БД: _Broker Enabled: True_, либо командой `ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET ENABLE_BROKER`.

Comment: @i-one подскажите, а если база активно используется, такой вариант безопасен `ALTER DATABASE db_name SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate` ?

Comment: В общем случае - нет, небезопасен, т.к. `with rollback immediate` откатит активные транзакции. Это может быть допустимо в каких-то случаях, в зависимости от того как приложения используют БД (например, делаются ли повторные попытки, если запрос не удался).

Answer (score 2):

-- Включение Service Broker:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET ENABLE_BROKER;
```

-- Выключение Service Broker:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET DISABLE_BROKER;
```

[Решение возможной проблемы ожидания при включении опции](http://rusanu.com/2006/01/30/how-long-should-i-expect-alter-databse-set-enable_broker-to-run/)